# How to display the content of note with evernote api

Tags: ios, evernote

I'm now developing an app on iOS with evernote api. Through getNoteContent function, I can get the content of a note, but how to display it? it's in ENML format.

Should I extract the information from ENML, and display it with UITextView? what's more, after user changed the content, Should I fill the changed content into ENML, and then send to Evernote server?

Or directly, display it with UIWebView? but how to edit the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying content is easier, although not trivial. You can convert ENML -> HTML pretty easily and display the converted note in a UIWebView.

Allowing a user to edit a note while maintaining formatting is much harder. Many of our apps have a full-time engineer who maintains the note editor, which is typically a web view in content-editable / design mode. I don't recommend trying to make a WYSIWYG Evernote note editor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again! From your answer, I think it could be hard for me to develop an note editor by myself. Is evernote support any api for this? Or any tools about HTML editor available from third part?

Comment: You can open Evernote's web-based note editor using URLs like https://HOST.evernote.com/edit/GUID, where GUID is the GUID of the note you want to edit. This will only work on desktop browsers, though.

Comment: Thanks, I have displayed note content in a UIWebView with javascript to make it editable.